# Tensorflow training on different subset of dataset each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data

I decided to build a large dataset with augmented images in order to save time during the training, which takes too long due to every image being augmented on the fly, thus reducing performance and GPU usage.

I was wondering if it is possible for every epoch to train on a subset of the dataset in order to save time (train on 4000 images instead of 40000). This is somehow similar to cross validation, but my aim is simply to reduce the portion of dataset on which the model is being trained every epoch, and alternating these small portions randomly. In cross validation of course I would not reduce my training dataset size, just alternate the validation set.

Answer (score 1):

By definition an epoch means that the entire dataset is passed trought the model for training. However you can use mini-batch training, divide the entire dataset into batches and train one batch at the time using .next_batch() function or by iterating over the dataset.

When you define your dataset you can use .shuffle() if you want the data in your bacthes to be randomly selected at each epoch and .batch(batch_size) to define how many samples to use for each batch.